# having trouble converting dictionary elements (string) into int

Tags: python, converters

Having a little trouble converting the two elements that are in a tuple inside of a dictionary into int values. the keys of the dictionary are country name and the tuple of info is (the area, the population). This is what i have so far :

```
def _demo_fileopenbox():        
    msg  = "Pick A File!"
    msg2 = "Select a country to learn more about!"
    title = "Open files"
    default="*.py"
    f = fileopenbox(msg,title,default=default)
    writeln("You chose to open file: %s" % f)

    countries = {}

    with open(f,'r') as handle:
        reader = csv.reader(handle, delimiter = '\t')  
        for row in reader:
            countries[row[0]] = (row[1].replace(',', ''), row[2].replace(',', ''))
            for i in countries:
                int((countries[i])[0]) 
                int((countries[i])[1])
        #while 1:
        #    reply = choicebox(msg=msg2, choices= list(countries.keys()) )
        #    writeln(reply + "-\tArea: " + (countries[reply])[0] + "\tPopulation: " + (countries[reply])[1] )
```

but i keep getting this error :

```
    int((countries[i])[0]) 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

any ideas how to fix this or a better way to do this:

Comment: You're getting an empty string in there somehow ... Take a look at your datafile ... Also note that just doing `int(countries[i][0])` won't change anything in your dictionary.

Comment: `int` isn't in-place either. You have to do `x = int(x)`.

Comment: @Blender -- I was just adding that to my comment :)

Comment: so is there a way in that lower for loop that i can actually change it could i just do something like `(countries[i])[0] = int((countries[i])[0])` ?